# HTML 5 Canvas Open-source Drawing Toolset API?

Tags: html, api, canvas, drawing

Is there an open-source toolkit out there that has a few simple canvas drawing tools built in? Think like a simple paint kit that can be applied to canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js